# "xml has more than 80 views" How to resolve?

Tags: android, xml, performance, view

I'm trying to create an algebraic calculator, but its xml file has more than 80 views.
[image]

As you can see, there are 35 buttons. The equation displayed has several special features, as the "x^2", the fractional number and the dividing line. The "^2" was created using html code into the java activity. Due to the fact that it's not possible to show the fractional numbers in one single TextView, I needed to create 2 TextViews for each fractional number, and its respective dividing line, which is made with a rectangle drawable whose layout_heigh is "1dp". I thought that I could create those "tv" programmatically, but I couldn't make it work because when I pressed the "x/y" (fractional number) button, the "tv" named "tvFN" was created inside an "if" sentence, this prevented me of using it outside, then, when I pressed the "button number 5", for instance, and I needed to show it in "tvFN", there wasn't such "tv". I am new with android development and I do not know what to do with this, so any idea will be thankfully welcome. Here's the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/LINEAR1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".408"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Llt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textUp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/rectangle"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textDown"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/texto2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textUp2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/rectangle2"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textDown2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- And so until textDown10 -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Llt_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textUp_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/rectangle_2"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textDown_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text2_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textUp2_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/rectangle2_2"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textDown2_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- And so until textDown10_2 -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/division"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingStart="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Igual"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-18dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/Division"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingStart="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Llt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextoUp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/Rectangle"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextoDown"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextUp2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/Rectangle2"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextDown2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- And so until TextDown10 -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Llt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Text_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextUp_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/Rectangle_1"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextDown_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Text_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextUp_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/Rectangle_2"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextDown_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- And so until TextDown_10 -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Here comes the button's code... -->
<!-- ... -->
```

I used 4 linear layouts to be able to visualize the fractional numbers in every possible part. (Imagine this equation (1/2)/(2/2) = (4/8)/(3/3) in the screen).

How can I either reduce the number of views or increase the activity performance?

Comment: Maybe try adding some of those views dynamically from the code and not directly in XML. You could also perhaps also think of creating different XMLs for some parts of the display and then programtically include them into one XML when needed? I am just guessing too.

Comment: First of, you don't need all these nested layouts. Which is **bad for performances**. Then you can rethink your UI using a GridView or a GridLayout and add the necessary Views at run time.

Comment: You can perform some optimization to the layout. Use GridLayout or PercentRelativeLayout for the button part.

Comment: In addition to @Rotwang's suggestion of flattening your layout, you should also look into using the `<include />` tag.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I'm gonna read some docs about GridViews and GridLayouts, but I don't have any idea about how to add the necessary Views at run time, because, as I wrote, if I declare a TV inside a button's onClickListener event, I won't be able of use it outside the "if". Do you know how?